# How to directly query workitem History in RTC using Java API

Tags: java, rtc, jazz, ibm-jazz

I want to get workitems by querying RTC based on workitem's history, after specific date and time.

Something like this:

```
IQueryableAttribute recAttr1 = factory.findAttribute(projectArea, IItem.HISTORY_PROPERTY, auditableClient, null );
AttributeExpression projectExpr = new AttributeExpression(projectAttr, AttributeOperation.EQUALS, projectArea);
AttributeExpression recExpr1 = new AttributeExpression(recAttr1, AttributeOperation.AFTER, timeStamp ); 
Term term= new Term(Operator.AND); 
term.add(recExpr1); 

IQueryClient queryClient = (IQueryClient) teamRepository.getClientLibrary(IQueryClient.class); 
IQueryResult<IResolvedResult<IWorkItem>> result = queryClient.getResolvedExpressionResults(projectArea, (Expression)term,    IWorkItem.FULL_PROFILE);
```

Is there any property like below?

> IItem.HISTORY_PROPERTY